# Do I collect steam trading cards in HL2: Episode 2 or only in the base HL2?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I played HL2: Episode 2 for about an hour but no steam trading card dropped. Do I have to play the base HL2 to get cards or are they also dropping in Episode 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Steam Trading Cards beta is currently limited to *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, *Team Fortress 2*, *Dota 2*, *Portal 2*, *Half-Life 2* and *Don't Starve*.

That means you'll have to play the base HL2 to earn trading cards, at least until HL2E2 is added to the list of participating games. (Half-Life 2 and its episodes are all independent games as far as Steam is concerned.)